# How to create region of specified color from window

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, win32gui

I have one window which is painted with some colorkey(16,0,16). Occasionally some part of window is getting painted by different colorkey. I would like to create a region out of this windows which has only my colorkey(16,0,16).

Please advice what is the best way to achieve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by region you mean an `HRGN`, then you can render the window to an in-memory bitmap and create an array of `RGNDATA` elements describing the rectangles where your colored pixels still exist, then pass that array to [`ExtCreateRegion()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162706.aspx) to create the `HRGN`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion. Actually I found one very interesting article  "http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Win32_Window_Skinning.shtml".     This article explains exactly what I was looking for.